# MongoDB: How to negate $elemMatch?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose we have the following collection structure:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "companies": [
        {
             "customers": [
                {
                     "name": "John",
                     "age": 20 
                },
                ...
             ]
        },
        ...
    ],
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "companies": [
        {
             "customers": [
                {
                     "name": "John",
                     "age": 22 
                },
                ...
             ]
        },
        ...
    ],
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "companies": [
        {
             "customers": [
                {
                     "name": "Bill",
                     "age": 30 
                },
                ...
             ]
        },
        ...
    ],
}
```

I want to implement an **exclude** functionality, so that if *name="John"* is given then only documents that don't have any customers named "John" should be returned (no problem with that)

However, if both `name="John"` and `age=20` are given, I only want documents which don't have any customers named "John" **and** being 20 years old.

For example:

name = John -> only document 3 is returned

name = John and age=20 -> documents 2 and 3 are returned

I tried using `$not($elemMatch)` but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: No because I want the filters to apply to an array element, as in `elemMatch`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$map` to apply your predicate to the `customers` array. Use `$allElementsTrue` to aggregate the result of the full result array. Apply this twice to `customers` level and `companies` level. You will get a flag `exclude` to indicate whether a document should be excluded.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "exclude": {
        "$allElementsTrue": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$companies",
            "as": "comp",
            "in": {
              "$allElementsTrue": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$comp.customers",
                  "as": "cust",
                  "in": {
                    // put your predicates here
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$cust.name",
                          "John"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$cust.age",
                          20
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "exclude": false
    }
  },
  // cosmetics
  {
    "$unset": "exclude"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lm-PW_u4SwF)